# seek () would like to 4G over the process in perl

Tags: perl, file, winapi, overflow

Please see the code first.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32API::File 0.08 qw( :ALL );

my $fh = Win32API::File->new("< \\\\.\\e:");
binmode $fh;

my $block_size = 512;
seek($fh, 8388607 * $block_size, 0);
read($fh, my $buf, $block_size);
my $s = 2 * length($buf);
print unpack("H$s",$buf);
```

I want to read / write access to direct a volume.

The code works normally.

```
seek($fh, 8388608 * $block_size, 0);
```

However, the above code does not work.

In the output, the data of the 0 address.

I think more than 4G values seem to be a problem. (overflow)

Please tell us the solution plz~

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with Perl, but I have experienced a similar issue when playing with files in Windows.  I would guess that the issue is trying to seek past 2 Gigabytes, when the `POSITION` parameter will wrap around to a negative number ("traditionally", file positions for these methods tend to be 32-bit signed values).  The solution I found was to not always seek from the beginning of the file... performing your seeks incrementally will allow the file system to point past the limits of the parameter types.

The parameters to [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) are:

```
seek (FILEHANDLE, POSITION, WHENCE)
```

The value of `WHENCE` should be `SEEK_SET` to seek from the beginning, `SEEK_CUR` to seek from the current position, and `SEEK_END` to seek from the `EOF` (the end of the file, generally meaning `POSITION` should be negative).

You should be able to confirm if this is the issue by altering your code (as a test) to do the seek in several steps, in increments of (say) `2097152 * $block_size`:

```
seek ($fh, 2097152 * $block_size, SEEK_SET);
seek ($fh, 2097152 * $block_size, SEEK_CUR); // seek from current position
seek ($fh, 2097152 * $block_size, SEEK_CUR); // seek from current position
seek ($fh, 2097152 * $block_size, SEEK_CUR); // seek from current position
read ($fh, my $buf, $block_size);
```